# Returning address of the rvalue input to function

Tags: c++, copy-elision, return-value-optimization

Today when reading a project's source code I came across an interesting example. In this example a template function's taking `T&&` and returning it back as `T&` after it's job done. This input is not an external / global object like std::ostream but something created locally and used. I created similar examples and at the end it's clear that in/out addresses are same. My question what happens if `function(T{})` used with a rvalue as input ? Like RVO I can see I'm holding rvalue's address after function returns. Isn't this a problem ?

```
#include <iostream>


auto println(auto&&...args) {

    ((std::cout << args), ...);

    std::cout << std::endl;
}

struct S {
    int value = 0;
};

S& foo(S& ins) {
    ins.value += 1;
    return ins;
}

const S& bar(const S& ins) {
    // nothing
    return ins;
}

S& zog(S&& ins) {
    println(std::hex, uintptr_t(&ins));
    return ins;
}

template <typename T>
T& kek(T&& param) {
    println(std::hex, uintptr_t(&param));
    return param;
}

int main() {
    S ins;
    println(std::hex, uintptr_t(&ins));
    println(std::hex, uintptr_t(&foo(ins)));
    println(std::hex, uintptr_t(&bar(ins)));

    // Ops
    S& s = zog(S{}); // RVO ? 
    println(std::hex, uintptr_t(&s));

    // lvalue
    int x = 0;
    // int& kek<int&>(int& param)...
    kek(x); 

    // const lvalue 
    const int y = 0;
    // const int& kek<const int&>(const int& param)... 
    kek(y);

    // rvalue
    // int& kek(int &&)... 
    int& temp = kek(0);
    // rvalue address still exists
    println(std::hex, uintptr_t(&temp));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you are asking about `s` it is just a dangling reference. I presume `&s` is UB.

Comment: Yes also `int& temp = kek(0)` too. If we think about RVO/copy ellision which allows us to continue to use a temporary memory what is the difference except this time that memory is a IN to function ? And why compiler can't detect this ? This is easily detectable in rust.

Comment: I don't believe copy elision comes into play at all, as the return type is a reference so there is no copy to elide.

Comment: *"And why compiler can't detect this ?"* Compilers are not required to detect this because there exists situations where it is impossible to make that determination. Consider that pointer arithmetic and casting between integer and pointer types is allowed. There exists legal c++ constructs that can't be statically determined, the validity of the code may depend on user inputs.

Comment: Assuming that the function definition is not visible at the calling site, the compiler have no way to know that return reference is temporary unless it would keep global informationfor that purpose. In practice, there are probably much more case where it is difficult to prove that returned data is dangling. For a function like the ones shown, it is probably assumed that calls might be chained like `kek(zog(S{}))`; otherwise, return type would have been `void`.